# How to send Firebase Auth Token ID from Mobile Clients (iOS & Android) for HTTPS triggers on Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Ok not an expert on server side coding and stuff but have a basic understanding. Here is my question;

- I have firebase triggers setup on cloud functions
- Now there is a requirement that I need to communicate with external servers to retrieve some other data
- So I use HTTPS triggers and I followed tutorials and managed to use express and other middlewares to get the job done

The problem is, I don't think I understand how these HTTP triggers are authenticated. I obviously want only the authenticated users to make a call to these end points and my users are either iOS or Android users.

**What i have already found out:**
I followed the code sample in this link: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js but I have one question

- It says The Firebase ID token needs to be passed as a Bearer token in the Authorization HTTP header like this: `Authorization: Bearer <Firebase ID Token>`
- Is this token passed automatically from iOS and android clients or do I need to manually call some FirebaseAuth get token function in the mobile SDKs and manually created this authorization bearer as a part of my request url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually call a Firebase API to get a token to pass to your backend.

This process is documented fairly thoroughly in the documentation for the Firebase Admin SDK, which you would use to [verify ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).  That link will give you examples for Android and iOS.

The code sample you linked to also has [client code for web that does the same](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authorized-https-endpoint/public/main.js#L68).

Comment: Understood. Thanks @Doug